# Image Stitching using Homography in C++

Tags: c++, image, homography

- Actually final image displaying me just first image. If I reverse the order it shows me only
  second image. It didnt perform actual stitching. I need to stitch them together proper. Keypoints are extracted and based on good keypoints homography is performed. When I try to wrap images it didnt perform as expected.  *

  ```
  Mat frame, frame2;
  cap >> frame;
  cap2 >> frame2;
  cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> kaze = cv::KAZE::create();
  std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kpts1, kpts2;
  cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
  kaze->detect(output1, kpts1);
  kaze->compute(output1, kpts1, descriptors1);
  kaze->detectAndCompute(output1, cv::noArray(), kpts1, descriptors1);

  kaze->detect(output, kpts2);
  kaze->compute(output, kpts2, descriptors2);
  kaze->detectAndCompute(output, cv::noArray(), kpts2, descriptors2);

  BFMatcher matcher;
  std::vector< DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);


  Mat img_matches = Mat::zeros(output1.size(), CV_8UC3);
  drawMatches(output1, kpts1, output, kpts2, matches, img_matches);


  double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;
  for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++)
  {
      double dist = matches[i].distance;
      if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
      if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
  }
  std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

  for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++)
  {
      if (matches[i].distance <= 3 * min_dist)//(matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist && 
      matches[i].distance > 3)
          {
              good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
          }
      }
  std::vector< Point2f > obj;
  std::vector< Point2f > scene;

  for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
  {
      obj.push_back(kpts1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
      scene.push_back(kpts2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
  }
  cv::Mat H = findHomography(scene, obj, RANSAC);
  Mat warpImage2;
  warpPerspective(frame2, warpImage2, H, Size(frame2.cols, frame2.rows), INTER_CUBIC);
  Mat final(Size(frame2.cols * 2 + frame.cols, frame2.rows * 2), CV_8UC3);
  Mat roi1(final, Rect(0, 0, frame.cols, frame.rows));
  Mat roi2(final, Rect(output.cols, 0, output.cols + warpImage2.cols, output.rows));
  warpImage2.copyTo(roi2);
  frame.copyTo(roi1);
  imshow("Final Stitched Video_Image", final);
  ```